# Venezuelan Passport

Tags: usa, passports, venezuelan-citizens

My venezuelan passport expires on July 2019. I would like to ask for an extension to my tourist stay. is the US accepting affidavits for expired Venezuelan passports as other countries: Canada, Peru, Colombia, etc. What is the process?

Comment: Do you intend to renew your Venezuelan passport?

Comment: You only need to submit an explanation if your passport will not be valid when you file I-539 for Extension of Status. Are you planning to file I-539 after July?

Comment: would your Visa still be valid after an hypothetical extension????

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.